# How to deploy API into API Gateway stage using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am trying to deploy lambda function into API Gateway using AWS CLI. I am using `aws apigateway put-integration` and `aws apigateway put-integration-response` to update the integration part. I am able to do till this part. Next step is I want to deploy this API into stage. I am using `aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id 1234123412 --stage-name dev`. But when I test API after I deploy, I am getting error message `Internal server error`. API works fine when I go to API Gateway console and on *Integration Request* and click on edit button of *Lambda Function* and don't modify function name, then go back and deploy manually. But I am not able get it work using AWS CLI. Is there any work around for this problem?

Comment: If you do everything from CLI, have you setup correct invocation permissions on your lambda function? Console does this automatically, but not CLI.

Comment: @Marcin Yes I am trying to do everything from CLI. I am not sure about it. How can I check or set up invocation permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `create-deployment`.

`aws apigateway create-deployment --region $REGION --rest-api-id $REST_API_ID --stage-name $STAGE_NAME`

This will create deployment and deploy it.

You can find $REST_API_ID here : `https://ap-northeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/main/apis`

Comment: If you have jq installed, then this might also help when scripting things:

 ```REST_ID=$(aws apigateway get-rest-apis | jq -r '.items[] | .id')
```
Followed by:


 ```aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id $REST_ID --stage-name dev`
 ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do an updateStage api call and patch the stage with the new deploymentId. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-stage.html

patch operation:

```
op: replace
path: /deploymentId
value: <id from create-deployment>.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-deployments.html